# Attempt to create two animations for cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I would like to create cell by expand and collapse. To do this i animate the cell by reloading. When i expand it works fine. But when i collapse it crashes and the reason is Attempt to create two animations for cell. I know Ive given same array paths and it wont reload two cell at the time. Is there a way to fix this.

I am new to coding, so i would be happy to get a simple solution.

Code:

The reason am using lastSelIPath is when first cell is expanded and touch the second cell the first cell would collapse and the second cell would expand.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSIndexPath* lastSelIPath = [ NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex_ inSection:0 ];

    [ tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES ];

    if (selectedIndex_ == indexPath.row)
    {
        selectedIndex_ = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        selectedIndex_ = indexPath.row;
    }

    NSIndexPath* ipath = [ NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0 ];

    NSArray* indexPathArr = [ NSArray arrayWithObjects:lastSelIPath, ipath, nil ];


    [ tableView beginUpdates ];

    [ tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArr withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic ];

    [ tableView endUpdates ];
}
```

So what i did now I set a condition and reload the one i wanted. Is it a correct method to follow please help.

Modified code:

```
if ( lastSelIPath.row == ipath.row )
    {
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ipath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
    else
    {
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[lastSelIPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ipath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
```

Comment: Its working with the condition I set above the code.

Answer (score 2):

Crash is right, you are trying to attempt two animation. Your indexPathArr contains two objects. Do not create this array and try this:

```
 [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[lastSelIPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ipath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Let me know, if it helps

Comment: It shows same error. When i try to close same cell again.

Comment: same cell means? lastSelIPath and ipath both are referencing to two different indexPath ?

Comment: No lastSelPath and iPath has same indexPath.row and on reload it shows the error.

Comment: anyways, I think you got your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath, oldIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

If newIndexPath is same as oldIndexPath, it will crash in iOS8, but this is fixed in iOS9 and later.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 if (selectedTag==1) {
    selectedIndex=indexPath.row;
    [self performSelector:@selector(Write Your Action) withObject:nil];
}
NSMutableArray *modifiedRows = [NSMutableArray array];
if ([indexPath isEqual:self.expandedIndexPath]) {
    [modifiedRows addObject:self.expandedIndexPath];
    self.expandedIndexPath = nil;
}
else {
    if (self.expandedIndexPath)
        [modifiedRows addObject:self.expandedIndexPath];
        self.expandedIndexPath = indexPath;
        [modifiedRows addObject:indexPath];
}
// This will animate updating the row sizes
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:modifiedRows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
// Preserve the deselection animation (if desired)
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


}
```

Using Selected Tag write the condition of your cell expand action. may be it helps.

Comment: Hey thx for the update. I've changed like this, i set a conding if lastSel and sel are equal reload only iPath. Else reload lastSelPath and iPath

if ( lastSelIPath.row == ipath.row )
    {
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ipath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
    else
    {
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[lastSelIPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ipath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party library for expanding cell.
https://github.com/bennyguitar/CollapseClick
 & implement there delegate method as

```
-(int)numberOfCellsForCollapseClick
{
}
-(NSString *)titleForCollapseClickAtIndex:(int)index {
}
-(UIView *)viewForCollapseClickContentViewAtIndex:(int)index {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will make sure to check the library.